# Can not create an optional/nullable foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have 2 models

```
public class Battle
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Event Event { get; set; }
        public int EventId { get; set; }
    }

public class Event 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<Battle> Battles { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to make `EventId` in the `Battles` table an optional foreign key.

I have tried several ways but non of them worked, FE:

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<Battle>()
                .HasOne(e => e.Event)
                .WithMany(e => e.Battles)
                .IsRequired(false);
```

or

```
public class Battle
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Event? Event { get; set; }
        public int? EventId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: The last example (with the both FK property and navigation being nullable types) should work. You can also combine it with the fluent configuration shown to be hundred percent sure. Btw, what EF Core version are you targeting? And do you have NRT enabled? Normally you don't need fluent configuration for this if using proper types and conventional names.

Comment: Yeap, NRT enabled, EF Core 6 @IvanStoev

Comment: I have tried both ways - didnt help. 

Also, I am getting this error when trying to save `Battle` entity with an `EventId` = 0.



`MySqlException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dbName`.`battles`, CONSTRAINT `FK_Battles_Events_EventId` FOREIGN KEY (`EventId`) REFERENCES `events` (`Id`))
`

Comment: This is different. You should use `null` instead of `0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I made a mistake, I was setting a `0` value to the `EventId` but it should be `null` or any int number > 0.